# How do I access one 'sibling' variable in a meteor template helper when I am in the context of another?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

How do I access one 'sibling' variable in a meteor template helper, when I am in the context of another? I want to determine whether the user that is logged in and viewing the page is the same user that posted the ride offering, so that I can hide or show the "bid" button accordingly.

For example, here is my template (html) file:

```
<!-- client/views/ride_offers.html -->
<template name="RideOfferPage">
    <p>UserIsOwner:{{UserIsOwner}}</p>
        {{#with CurrentRideOffer}}
            {{> RideOffer}}
        {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="RideOffer">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <p><a href="{{RideOfferPagePath this}}">Details</a>, Author: {{author}}, From: {{origin}}, To: {{destination}}, between {{earliest}} and {{latest}} for {{nseats}} person(s). Asking ${{price}}. 
      <a href="{{MakeBidOnOfferPath this}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Bid</button></a><p>
      <p>UserIsOwner:{{UserIsOwner}}</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

And here is my JavaScript file:

```
Template.RideOfferPage.helpers({ 
    CurrentRideOffer: function() {
        return RideOffers.findOne(Session.get('CurrentOfferId')); 
    },
    UserIsOwner: function() {
        return RideOffers.find({_id: Session.get('CurrentOfferId'), userId: Meteor.userId()}).count() > 0;
    }
});
```

In the "RideOffer" template, I am able access the variables `author`, `origin`, ..., `price`. But I am unable to access the boolean `UserIsOwner`. I am, however, able to access the boolean `UserIsOwner` in the "RideOfferPage" template.

Does anyone know how I can access the boolean `UserIsOwner` in the "RideOffer" template?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the userIsOwner function outside the helper as an anonymous function and then call it from both templates.

```
Template.RideOfferPage.helpers({ 
  CurrentRideOffer: function() {
    return RideOffers.findOne(Session.get('CurrentOfferId')); 
  },
  UserIsOwner: checkUserIsOwner()
});

Template.RideOffer.helpers({ 
  UserIsOwner: checkUserIsOwner()
});

checkUserIsOwner= function() {
  return RideOffers.find({_id: Session.get('CurrentOfferId'), userId: Meteor.userId()}).count() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh and you can also register userIsOwner as a global helper using Handlebars.registerHelper("UserIsOwner", function() {
   return RideOffers.find({_id: Session.get('CurrentOfferId'), userId: Meteor.userId()}).count() > 0;
});

Comment: Dear Serkan, thanks for replying. It looks like a great approach, but I cannot get it to work (probably for some simple reason that will be obvious to me only when this is solved). For example, if in each of the templates I hardcode `UserIsOwner: true` or `UserIsOwner: false`, then I get the behavior in the page that I expect from using those values. But if I put instead `UserIsOwner: checkUserIsOwner()` (with `checkUserIsOwner` defined as above), the templates don't have access to `UserIsOwner`. Even if I use `return true` in `checkUserIsOwner`, it still doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I found it: instead of `UserIsOwner: checkUserIsOwner()` the code should be `UserIsOwner: function() {
   return checkUserIsOwner()
  }`. I don't quite know why, but for now just glad it works. Thanks!

Comment: Oh well, I my have overlooked a simple javascript semantic, but I'm glad you've solved your problem. I've also learned something here, so this is a clear win win :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you're asking.

In your particular example you are not asking about siblings, but about parents, since the `RideOfferPage` template renders the `RideOffer` template. You can access variables in the parent data context (**but not helpers**) like so:

```
<template name="RideOffer">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <!-- 
         other stuff 
       -->
      <p>UserIsOwner:{{../UserIsOwner}}</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

In other cases, you may have a template being rendered as a sibling of this one. In that case, you can't actually know what the sibling is until the template is actually on the page; however, you can find it in the `rendered` callback:

```js
Template.foo.rendered = function() {
    var current = this.firstNode;
    var next = $(currentItem).next(); // or .prev()

    if (next.length) {
      nextData = Spark.getDataContext(next[0]);
    }         
    // Do something with nextData
};
```

Finally, you can get the parent context of any rendered DOM element by repeatedly iterating through its parents. This isn't super efficient but I've used it in places where there is extensive drag and drop with `DOMFragment`s moving around on the page:

```js
Template.bar.events = {
  "click .something": function(e) {

    var target = e.target;
    var context = Spark.getDataContext(target);
    var parentContext = context;        
    while (parentContext === context) {
      parentContext = Spark.getDataContext(target = target.parentNode);
    }
    // Do something with parentContext
  }
};
```

I'm curious to know if there is a better way to do the last thing, which may potentially have to iterate through many DOM elements. In any case, you may want to check out my [meteor-autocomplete](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete) package for this and other cool tricks.